# Light Gray color in beamer

Tags: color

I want to know how to define a light gray color with beamer. I am using this color
to shade a small block of my text.

Here is the code I am using for defining my colors.

`\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.01,0.199,0.1}`

The current color is giving me a very dark green. I am not sure how to change this 
to light gray. Can some one help with this ?

Beamer only seems to be accepting values between 0 and 1.

This link does give values for gray but I think it is for some other units. 
http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/

Comment: Shades of gray consist of equal amounts of **r** ed, **g** reen and **b** lue, so you could use something like `\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}` or `\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}`.

Comment: You can also simply say: `\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!40}` (which means 40%gray and 60% white).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use some predefined gray color and the `!` syntax together with `\colorlet`; for example:

```
\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!40}
```

(40% gray and 60% white); increasing the value used will produce darker shades and decreasing it, lighter ones.

Answer (score 3):

The Link you provided, mentiones the values of RGB (red green blue as mention by @Jake in the comments above) in a range from 0 to 255, i.e. in 8 bit values each. To convert to your needs, divide the values by 256. You can even let beamer to the calcucaltions and use fractions. For example `\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{190/256,190/256,190/256}` should work as fine as `\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.7421875,0.7421875,0.7421875}` using the values for gray from your link

Comment: `beamer` and TikZ use `xcolor` under the hood so you can directly use integer models via `\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{190,190,190}` Hex model is also supported.

Comment: Oh, i forgot about that, of course; it does. So for integer values colors (`0..255`) `xcolor` provides the capital `RGB` color model and for percental values (`0..1`) the `rgb` model. Thanks for the hint.